# Applying formula on saved search columns

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

We are trying to generate a report to find out turn around time (TAT) of our deliveries of orders, categorize them in different buckets like 0-5 days, 5-8 days, etc.

I am able to get the count of orders delivered within these buckets using the saved search formula **(numeric)** with summary type as sum:

> Example:
>       case when trunc ({custbody_dlight_kspdeliverydate})-{trandate} between 0 and 5 then {quantity} else 0 end

Now, I also want to get percentage of orders delivered in each bucket. How can I get that?

Secondly, I also want to consider holidays while doing this TAT calculation. currently, delivery date - trandate will give me calendar dates only. If there is a weekend in between or a declared holiday, the result should be able to consider that. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a delivery date one way to get the number of business days between two dates would be to add another custom field and use a User Event script to update the TAT into that field. 
This would let you use a calendar aware script that could manage not only weekends but also any statutory holidays.

I have a couple of SS1.0 examples of date calc scripts in the repo at https://github.com/BKnights/KotN-Netsuite that you could use as samples.